# Speed of encrypted flash drive

Tags: performance, disk-encryption, aes

I've encrypted my Transcend Jetflash flash drive (16 GB, USB2, ext2).
Before the operation, the flash drive's speed was:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/media/JetFlash/file bs=1M count=256
```

*Results with: 26,5 s, 10,1 Mb/s*

Then I encrypted it:

```
# losetup -e AES128 /dev/loop1 /dev/sdb
# mkfs -t ext2 /dev/loop1
# losetup -d /dev/loop1
# mkdir /mnt/tmp
# mount /dev/sdb -o loop=/dev/loop1,encryption=AES128 /mnt/tmp -t ext2
# losetup -e AES128 /dev/loop1 /dev/sdb
```

And I've executed the same command:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/tmp/file bs=1M count=256
```

*Results with: 11,98 s, 22,4 Mb/s*

For AES256 the result was:
12,83 s, 20,9 Mb/s

Can somebody explain what's happening?
Why does an encrypted flash drive works twice as fast?

Comment: I think that's not a programming related question and therefore the wrong place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Some guesses:

1. The encryption device is compressing before encrypting.
2. Writing ones to flash is faster than writing zeros.

Comment: Do you've a source?

Comment: @Lekensteyn No, just guessing. Compression before encryption is good practice.

Comment: I do think that compression is something for the filesystem, not the encryption itself? Do you've a source for your second guess? It sounds a little weird.

Comment: I know there have been encryption schemes in the past that compressed.  Since the encryption code is inserting itself in the file access path the way it is, compression at the same time is fairly trivial.

Comment: And, yes, randomizing the data (as encryption does) may allow faster writing to a flash -- several possible mechanisms for that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it has to do with write cache, the LUKS layer might act as a cache too, but in the end, it's still limited by the disk speed.

Try writing a bigger file, it should give more realistic results. To test the time needed for writing to the flash drive, run a `sync` command after doing the `dd` command. Now measure the time before running `dd` and after `dd` using the `date` program.